# Given a Redis RDB snapshot, is there a way to extract OBJECT IDLETIME of keys?

Tags: redis

The background is that in production Redis Cluster, after a long period of feature iteration there're a bunch of keys are either problematic or inactive for long, e.g. lack of TTL.

To have a systematic way to catch all questionable keys I started analysing nightly snapshot with RDB libs like https://github.com/HDT3213/rdb.

So,

1. Is OBJECT IDELTIME captured in rdb snapshot?
2. Any advice to extract it for further analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is OBJECT IDELTIME captured in rdb snapshot?

NO. And you cannot get the idle time from RDB file.

> Any advice to extract it for further analysis?

Why not scan keys in the online data set with a small *count* option, and collect the info with `OBJECT IDELTIME` command? If you use a small *count* option, it won't have big penalty on the performance of the online service.